# Type Conversion (int to string)

Tags: java, type-conversion

We can't convert from int to string then how and why the given code is running without any issue?

```java
int i = 5;
String str = "";
str = str + i;
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
55
```

Why I am getting output as 55 as we can't convert from int to string?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. There is a mismatch between your code and output.

```
jshell> int i = 5;
i ==> 5

jshell> String str = "";
str ==> ""

jshell> str = str + i;
str ==> "5"
```

Comment: Heh, good catch about the 55 vs 5. Still, it is possible to convert int to String.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator is overloaded for `String` and e.g, `int`, and it converts the `int` first to `Integer`, then to `String`, and finally concatenates the two strings.

See [the Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/expressions.html#15.18.1)

Also note that you can convert anything, including `Integer`, to `String` by calling the [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toString()) method inherited from `Object`.